# Android image upload issue

Tags: php, android, android-async-http

I am developing an Android application for airport customer complain lodging and tracking.The user will enter their passenger ID,complain text and an image(optional)...i am using the Asynchronous Http Client library to upload the image to the server...

my client end code to upload image is-

```
File myfile=new File(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
params.put("image",myfile);
```

i am saving the image captured by the camera in photoFile.
Then i am making a POST request and sending the Complain ID(generated on client-side),Complain text and image to the server.

On server side i am using PHP,the code goes like this-

```
$complain_id=$_POST['complain_id'];
$ticket_id=substr($complain_id,-6);
$complain=$_POST['complain_text'];
$imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] , "/images/".$imageName);
$imageData = file_get_contents( "/images/".$imageName);
$imageData = addslashes($imageData);
$imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];


$sql='INSERT INTO `complain_table` (`complain_id`, `ticket_id`, `complain_text`, `complain_image`, `complain_audio`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)';
$query=$db->prepare($sql);
$values=array($complain_id, $ticket_id, $complain, $imageData, NULL);;
$query -> execute($values);
$fetch_sql=$sql="SELECT Name, Email FROM  `person_table` WHERE ticket_id ='".$ticket_id."'";
$fetch_query=$db->prepare($fetch_sql);
$fetch_query->execute();
$fetch_obj=$fetch_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$admin_email = "Abhijog@feedbackdesignlab.com";
$email =$fetch_obj->Email;
$user_name=$fetch_obj->Name;
$subject = 'Complain Registration';
$comment = 'Dear '.$user_name.', your Complain ID is '.$complain_id.'. Use the Complain ID to track your complain.';
mail($email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $admin_email);
echo "The complain has been lodged.Please check your e-mail for the complain ID for tracking";
```

Everthing is getting inserted in the database except the image.I can't find any bug in my code.please help

Comment: Can i see the complete Java Code for Sending Image to the Server. ?

Comment: the client side is working fine...i am opening the camera on a button click and saving the image in the pictures directory..here is the code..

Comment: TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     Cid="C" + (tm.getDeviceId()) + PID ;
                    RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
                    params.put("complain_id",Cid);
                    params.put("complain_text",Complain)

Comment: "Then i am making a POST request and sending the Complain ID(generated on client-side),Complain text and image to the server." then  where do you make your POST request?

Comment: What's thisss ??I think, You should use the `MultipartEntity` from the `org.apache.http.entity.mime` to send files through the Http. am not a pro so can't sure about the solution.

Comment: client.post("http://www.feedback.zz.mu/newpostinsert.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Complain has been registered.Please check your email for details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

Comment: @ Arupam - Check the file size in your php to ensure the file is actually sent to the server.  $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
 echo $size;

Comment: Yeah, check the filesize.

Comment: the filesize is zero..

Comment: the file is not getting send to the server...